# How do I save an entire VB6 project to a new folder? Modules and all

Tags: vb6

How do I save an entire VB6 project to a new folder? Modules and all. I'm in a position where I need to work with some old VB6 projects. I'd like to save them to a new folder but when I save the project, all that is saved is the vbp file. No modules, no frm files. I want to be able to save all the info to a single folder without moving each BAS file one at a time. Is this even possible?

Addition: The first 2 replies make good sense. But my problem is that the BAS modules seem to be scattered all over the place. Making Windows Explorer do the work a bit tricky. If I have to I will but was looking for an easier way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean from within Visual Studio, I don't think you can except by doing `Save As` for each file...

But the simpler approach is to just use Windows Explorer and copy the whole folder structure for the solution into another folder, (or do a recursive "Get" from your source code repository to a different local destination), and then open the solution or project file in the new location... The pointers in the project file that tell Visual Studio where 5all the individual source code and other files are located are generally all stored as relative paths, relative to the folder that the project file is in...

Comment: All good answers but this is the technique I used. Thanks everyone

Comment: on a side note: if you have relative/absolute paths to registered references or components, it is possible to delete the directory from the pathname. it seems to me unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

Given the new "addition" to the question:

1. Move the VBP and the files in Windows Explorer to a completely new directory.
2. Open the VBP in a text editor and change any absolute paths to relative paths. VBP files are simple text files, and the format is even [documented in the VB6 manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716294(VS.60).aspx).

Here's an example. This evil VBP below has many absolute paths

```
Type=Exe 
Form=c:\who\knows\where\B_Form.frm 
Module=CModule; z:\magic\mapped\network\drive\heehee\C_Module.bas 
Class=DClass; x:\personal\usb\stick\D_Class.cls
```

It would be changed to this benign VBP, which references local copies of the files. You can use relative paths for subdirectories.

```
Type=Exe 
Form=B_Form.frm 
Module=CModule; C_Module.bas 
Class=DClass; subdirectory\D_Class.cls
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used VB6, but I'd be tempted to move them using Windows Explorer, then manually edit the VBP file to point to the new locations afterwards. If I remember right, relative paths are fine in the VBP, so you may not even need to manke any changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Unbind from source control, if capable/appropriate.
2. Check into source control as a brand new solution/project
3. Recursive 'get' from your SCM into a new directory.
4. There's your new copy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a VB6 Add-in. You can download it from: http://pan.baidu.com/s/1CXO3k
Or you can use below code to create your own.

```
Option Explicit

Public VBInstance As VBIDE.VBE
Public Connect As Connect

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
Connect.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Dim strProject As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strPath2 As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPrjFile As String
Dim rst As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim m, n As Long
Dim col2 As Collection, col As Collection
Dim vbCom As VBComponent
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim f1 As String, f2 As String

strProject = Me.VBInstance.ActiveVBProject.FileName
strPath = ParseFileName(strProject, strPrjFile)

strPath2 = setFolder

If strPath = "" Or strPath = strPath2 Then
    MsgBox "target folder is invalid or same as the project folder. Can't copy."
    Exit Sub
End If
Set col2 = New Collection
Set col = New Collection
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath2 & "\wemeet.log", False)
For m = Me.VBInstance.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set vbCom = Me.VBInstance.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(m)
    For n = 1 To vbCom.FileCount
        f1 = vbCom.FileNames(n)
        ParseFileName f1, strFile
        f2 = strPath2 & "\" & strFile
        fso.CopyFile f1, f2
        col.Add f1
        col2.Add f2
        ts.WriteLine "" & Now() & " [Move]: " & f1
        ts.WriteLine "" & Now() & " [To  ]: " & f2
        ts.WriteBlankLines 1
    Next
    Me.VBInstance.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbCom
Next
For m = 1 To col2.Count
    Me.VBInstance.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.AddFile col2.Item(m)
    ts.WriteLine "" & Now() & " [Add]: " & col2.Item(m)
    ts.WriteBlankLines 1
Next

Me.VBInstance.ActiveVBProject.SaveAs strPath2 & "\" & strPrjFile
ts.WriteLine "" & Now() & " [SaveAs]: " & strPath2 & "\" & strPrjFile
ts.WriteBlankLines 1
ts.Close
fso.OpenTextFile strPath2 & "\wemeet.log"
Set fso = Nothing
Set col = Nothing
Set col2 = Nothing
Set vbCom = Nothing
Connect.Hide
End Sub

Private Function ParseFileName(ByVal sPath As String, ByRef sFile As String) As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
If fso.FileExists(sPath) Then
    ParseFileName = fso.GetParentFolderName(sPath)
    sFile = fso.GetFileName(sPath)
Else
    ParseFileName = ""
    sFile = ""
End If
Set fso = Nothing
End Function


Private Function setFolder() As String
Dim objDlg As Object
Dim objStartFolder As Object
Set objDlg = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objStartFolder = objDlg.BrowseForFolder(&H0, "Select a folder", &H10 + &H1)

If InStr(1, TypeName(objStartFolder), "Folder") > 0 Then
    setFolder = objStartFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(objStartFolder.Title).Path
End If
Set objDlg = Nothing
End Function
```